# OWASP ZAP HTTP POST scans not performed with imported URLs

Tags: continuous-integration, owasp, zap

I'd like to use ZAP in headless mode to scan a given set of URLs. Here is what I did:

- I started ZAP UI
- configured it as a HTTP_PROXY for a browser
- navigated my website (including GET/POS/PUT actions during the journey)
- created a context and added the relevant urls
- performed an active scan on the context

In this scenario every thing was fine: the active scan performed several GET/POST/PUT attacks as intended.

Then in order to prepare for setup in the CI and simulate the behavior there I

- exported the context and it's urls
- cleared the context/urls/history
- imported the context and urls (via rest-api)
- performed an active scan against the imported context

As a result I only see GET-Attacks against the URLs.

I could certainly set up a CI-Pipeline with some kind of browser based ui tests using ZAP as a proxy (as I did manually before performing active scan), but this I'd like to avoid.

So what is the way to tweack ZAP to perform POST attacks on imported URLs?

**Edit**: the POST/PUT-Parameters are send in the Request-Body or as part of the URL following the REST-Style (e.g. `method/param-1-key/param-1-value`) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just used it the wrong way. The answer is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zaproxy-users/fVdsxqGaHiM